# Getting the value in the React material-UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am referring to the documentation of React Material-UI (https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/).

In the demo code,

```
    <Autocomplete
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option: FilmOptionType) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
      )}
    />
```

I get how it works, but I am not sure how I am supposed to get the selected value.

For example, I want to use the `onChange` prop to this so that I can make some actions based on the selection.

I tried adding `onChange={v => console.log(v)}`

but the `v` does not show anything related to the selected value.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Can't believe that the project still hasn't clearly documented this!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Solved by using passing in the `(event, value)` to the `onChange` props.

```
<Autocomplete
    onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value)} // prints the selected value
    renderInput={params => (
        <TextField {...params} label="Label" variant="outlined" fullWidth />
    )}
/>
```

Comment: How add onsubmit?

Comment: I spent hours on end trying to get this value right, this solved beautifully.

Comment: Nice! Minor addendum someone might fight useful: In case of the user typing in an arbitrary value (like `freeSolo`), there's no `onChange` event. However, there's `onInputChange` and I'm tracking the value in the component state, so I can use it when the user clicks on an "add" button. I'm using both events.

Comment: how do i get the index of the item selected? meaning if i select the first one, i want 0 and so on

Comment: How i get multiples autocomplete values?

Comment: Hey @SteveAngello - have you found a way to get multiple autocomplete values?

Comment: Can you get the `option.title`/`getOptionLabel`  in the `onChange` callback?

Answer (score 8):

The `onChange` prop works for multiple autocomplete values as well (@Steve Angello @ShwetaJ). The `value` returned is a list of all the selected options.

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);

const handleChange = (event, value) => setSelectedOptions(value);

const handleSubmit = () => console.log(selectedOptions);

.
.
.

<Autocomplete
  multiple
  autoHighlight
  id="tags-outlined"
  options={top100Films}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
  onChange={handleChange}
  filterSelectedOptions
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      variant="standard"
    />
  )}
/>

.
.
.


<button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit!</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `useState` to store the recevied value and `onChange` to get the value:

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);


return (
    <Autocomplete
        onChange={(event, value) => setSelected(value)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="selected" />}
    />
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is **TS** working example

```
  const tags = ["perimeter", "Algebra", "equation", "square root"];

  const handleInput = (e: React.SyntheticEvent, value: string[]) => {
    console.log(value);
  };

<Autocomplete
    multiple
    options={tags}
    onChange={handleInput}
    renderTags={(value: readonly string[], getTagProps) =>
    value.map((option: string, index: number) => (
            <Chip
                variant="outlined"
                label={option}
                {...getTagProps({ index })}
             />
            ))
           }
           renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
               {...params}
               variant="filled"
               label="Tags"
               placeholder="select question tags"
           />
        )}
   />
```

============ Output ===============

[image]